# I want to prefer /usr/bin/echo versus built-in echo in Ubuntu within Webmin - I've asked in that specific forum too

Tags: bash, echo, ubuntu-22.04, webmin

RE: Webmin Question

SYSTEM INFORMATION
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (AWS Instance)   Codename: jammy
Webmin version  2.010
I’ve got tons of custom commands in Webmin. In RHEL they used to work fine but some of the custom commands have “echo -e” in menu’s that are built. I noticed the “-e” is showing up in the menus because echo isn’t recognizing the “-e”. This is due to webmin utilizing the built-in echo within the shell versus /usr/bin/echo.

If I modify the custom command and replace /usr/bin/echo for the “echo” then the “-e” get’s used as intended and doesn’t show up on the custom command menu. Is there any way to ask webmin to prefer the /usr/bin/echo versus the built in? I understand there are security reasons for echo being built-in but so far I don’t have a reason to NOT switch the behavior of webmin if possible. TIA.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `echo` in the first place; use `printf` instead. I'm not aware of any *security* reasons for making `echo` a built-in, (at least, none that are specific to `echo`), only performance reasons.

Comment: BTW, the meaning of `echo -e` depends on whether the `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are actively enabled. This is all configurable at runtime (or compile time). Mind, `xpg_echo` is disabled, and `echo -e` behaves the way you expect it to (which is NOT the way POSIX specifies it to be have) out-of-the-box on bash, so that implies your real shell interpreter is not bash but some sh variant (ash, dash, etc); which is particularly likely on Ubuntu.

Comment: Even the POSIX standard for `echo` recommends using `printf` instead; see APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: Also, on [unix.se], see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113). Be careful to keep your data and format strings separate; the equivalent to `echo -e "$foo"` is `printf '%b\n' "$foo"`, not `printf "$foo\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enable -n echo` which will disable the builtin echo command and force your script to use the one on your path.

Comment: True, but I suspect rather strongly that the OP is incorrect to think that their active shell is bash (unless they did the work to `shopt -s xpg_echo`, which is... not so likely to happen without knowing about it). They're tagged as ubuntu; `sh` on ubuntu is dash, which explains the `echo`-not-honoring-`-e` behavior, but also means that `enable` won't be found if run in `sh`.

Comment: RE: enable -n echo  at the CLI didn't seem to do anything.